# Jquery and css files are overwritten with html code when deploying on glassfish 4.0

Tags: java, jquery, css, jsp, glassfish

I have an EJB with servlet project and JSP as front end pages.
I'm trying to deploy the project on a glassfish 4.0 server. Everything worked fine until now, when all my jquery and css files are overwritten with html of the current jsp page. I have no idea what is happening.
All the jquery and css files look ok in project folders.
See bellow print screen.
Anyone encountered this wired behaviour??

> Overwritten jquery

[image]

> Overwritten CSS

[image]

Comment: Your configuration is wrong for glassfish.  It is just giving you a redirection.   You have to configure your dispatcher/handler etc.  That depends on your framework

Comment: I haven't made any changes to the configuration, just developing new capabilities in java code... before that same server,same configuration worked. Is it possible to alter glassfishes configuration from backend code?

Comment: I'm talking about the webapp configuration.  You have to ensure that your dispatcher/router is found, and deal with any runtime problems.  Your best bet is to look through logs

Comment: Ok, I'll check the logs, seems some get methods are playing with dispatcher

Comment: Your images are very hard to read. Please insert the actual text into your question to improve the formatting.

Comment: if you right click and save image on your pc, should see the text ok